# Python: Add an empty Binary Registry key

Tags: python, registry

How to add a Registry key, of Binary type, that has no value? (zero-length binary value)

What should I give in the last argument in this function call?

```
    SetValueEx(registryKey, "myKey", 0, REG_BINARY, ???)
```

I would like the Registry key to be like:

[image: Empty binary registry key]

Comment: `0x0000` already a empty value, `None` and `False` not a binary value !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some researching, I found that the missing arg is `None`.

The code should be:

```
    SetValueEx(registryKey, "myKey", 0, REG_BINARY, None)
```